# Why I get error "Could not find domain: default" when import core Murano library during manual installation

Tags: openstack, keystone, fiware-murano

I'm in the middle of installing Murano using this guide: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/murano/draft/admin-guide/deploy_murano/install_manually.html and got stack when I try to import core Murano libarary.

I installed a standard OpenStack Mitaka on CentOS 7 and use domain default successfully with other service, but when I execute the follow command:

```
$tox -e venv -- murano --os-user-domain-name default --os-project-name admin --os-username admin --os-auth-url http://controller:35357/v3  --murano-url http://controller:8082   package-import --is-public io.murano.zip
```

I get this error:
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)

looking on the logs I see that:

```
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers [req-f4b6a4f8-d16c-4d7d-9c26-9859ee1e0a32 - - - - -] Could not find domain: default
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/auth/controllers.py", line 187, in _lookup_domain
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     domain_ref = self.resource_api.get_domain(domain_id)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/manager.py", line 124, in wrapped
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     __ret_val = __f(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 1053, in decorate
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     should_cache_fn)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 657, in get_or_create
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     async_creator) as value:
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 158, in __enter__
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     return self._enter()
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 98, in _enter
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     generated = self._enter_create(createdtime)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 149, in _enter_create
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     created = self.creator()
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 625, in gen_value
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     created_value = creator()
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 1049, in creator
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     return fn(*arg, **kw)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/resource/core.py", line 704, in get_domain
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers     raise exception.DomainNotFound(domain_id=domain_id)
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers DomainNotFound: Could not find domain: default
ERROR keystone.auth.controllers
WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [req-f4b6a4f8-d16c-4d7d-9c26-9859ee1e0a32 - - - - -] Authorization failed. The request you have made requires authentication.
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Dedi

Comment: Are you certain the settings in the `keystone_authtoken` section of the murano configuration file are correct? Have you compared them to the same section of the config files from other services?

Comment: @larsks, yes I did the comparison and it's the same as the section on other conf files in rest of the services.

Comment: Do other openstack clients/commands work? Which version of keystone API are you using? It looks like you don't have default domain in keystone. Searching for "Could not find domain, default" error nets some keystone similar keystone-related errors.

Comment: @teferi other clients/commands work well. I'm using keystone v3

Comment: check your user password of murano in keystone and make sure you have right role assignment policy